# How to pass a value to an AngularJS $http success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

In my AngularJS application I am doing the following

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success(function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        console.log(data);
        // Here I would also need the value of 'key'
    }
});
```

Now I need to access the `key` value within the success callback, i.e. I need to know which value it had when the `get()` request has been made.

Any "best practice" how to do so?

PS: I can do the following, but is there a better way?

```
var key = config.url.split('/')[2];
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing it directly? It will be available, try `console.log(key)`

Comment: Yes that doesn't work, also that callback is asynchronous, so the value of key could have been changed already when it is being called.

Comment: @TeamAIGD -- You should definitely have access to `key` inside the callback, and if `key` is going to be changing that much, assign `key` to a different variable right before the call, then use that variable in the callback.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
$scope.key = key;
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success(function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        console.log(data, $scope.key);
    }
});
```

Solution 2 (Updated per Jim Hong's observation in his answer):

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success((function(key) {
    return function(data) {
        console.log(key, data);
    }
})(key));
```

Comment: Second solution works for iteration with callbacks. I used it for this: for(var i = 0; i < somelist.length; i++){ doHttpRequest().callback((function(i){ return function(data, etc) { // Do something with the iterator value } }(i))

Comment: The second solution works for me. I've edited it to incorporate the correction mentioned by Jim Hong in his answer below.

Comment: .success is deprecated. Use then instead

Answer (score 13):

Reference to @geniuscarrier
The working solution on my side is

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success((function(key) {
    return function(data) {
        console.log(key, data);
    }
})(key));
```

Since using @geniuscarrier, I'l get

> data undefined error

.

Comment: Good point. I've edited @geniuscarrier 's answer to correct it -  a note to readers who are wondering whats different in your answer and geniuscarrier's second solution. They are now the same.

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, this is not an AngularJS problem but a feature of **javascript**

first of all, **functions** that you defined inside a **scope** will have access to *local variable* and *parameter* of its *parent* scope

```
function parent(arg){
   var local
   function child(){
       // have access to arg and local
   }
}
```

Scope actually works well with the parent-child analogy: if you are the parent and you **own** a cookie, of cause you are welling to share it with your children...but if you are a kid...your cookie is **your** cookie, your parent is not allowed to touch it :). In other words, inner scope can access outer scope but it does not work both ways

So you should definitely be able to do:

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success(function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        console.log(data, key); //as long as you can pass it to $http.get as an argument
                                //you can access it here
    }
});
```

Secondly, because of the event-driven nature of javascript, [inner function store ***references*** to the outer function’s variables](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/). you probably have heard of this

> functions in javascript are objects

local variables and parameters are thus private members of the function:

```
function ObjectA(){ // define a constructor
    var x = 10      // private variable
    changeX : function(){
                  x = 20   // access and MODIFY a variable of parent scope
              }
}
```

if you can understand how private variable works in javascript, then you basically understand what **closure** is. Thus, for call back function, it is very possible that by the time it is triggered, the value of the parent scope variable is already changed. To fix this, you can use an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** (IIFE)

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success((function(currentKeyValue) {
    return function(data) {
        console.log(currentKeyValue, data);
        // again, currentKeyValue is a REFERENCE to outer function's
        // parameter. However, since String is passed by value in javascript
        // currentKeyValue of outer scope is a DIFFERENT string that has the
        // same value as KEY when it is invoked
    }
})(key)); // immediately invoke the function passing the key as a parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of polluting scope or complicating with iif, another cleaner way is to create a callback function and call it with parameters;

```
var myCallBack = function (key) {
  return function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      console.log(data, key);
    }
  }
}

$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').success(myCallBack(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

Phew, I was looking for this answer for so long, but it's good it is here. Just to update it, since legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated and we should use the standard `then` method instead.

Solution 2 in @geniuscarrier and @jim-horng answers may be rewritten like this:

```
$http.get('/plugin/' + key + '/js').then(
    (function(key) {
        return function(data) {
            console.log(key, data);
        }
    })(key),
    function(data) {
        //error handle
    });
```