# AngularJS controller only updating part of the data

Tags: python, angularjs

I have a small bottle server that returns random values given a `machineID` as shown below:

```
@app.route('/dataMachine')
@enable_cors
def simulatedMachineData():

    prevVals = {'machineID_1': 0,'machineID_2': 0, 'machineID_3': 0,}
    devVals = {'machineID_1': 5.3,'machineID_2': 2.1,'machineID_3': 7.1,}    

    dictVals  = bottle.request.query.decode()
    machineID = dictVals.get('machine', '')
    if machineID not in devVals.keys(): return '-1'
    prevVals[machineID] += normal(scale=devVals[machineID])
    return str(prevVals[machineID])
```

This does not have a problem.

Now I have an AngularJS app that ties to interact with this data, as shown below:

```
var app = angular.module('testBidirection', []);

app.controller('tempCntrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval){

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Data to display and its update function
    $scope.data = {
        'machineID_1':'0',
        'machineID_2':'0',
        'machineID_3':'0',
    };

    var machineIDs = ['machineID_1', 'machineID_2', 'machineID_3'];
    $scope.machineID = 'machineID_1';

    $scope.getData = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                $scope.machineID = machineIDs[i];
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMachine?machine=' + $scope.machineID).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.data[ $scope.machineID ] = data;
                });
        };
    };


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Button controller. Use this controller to 
    //      toggle the initiation of getting and 
    //      stopping data retrieval ...
    $scope.buttonText = 'start Comm';
    $scope.toggleComm = function(){
        if ($scope.buttonText == 'start Comm') {
            $scope.buttonText = 'stop Comm';
            stop = $interval($scope.getData, 2*1000);
        } else {
            $scope.buttonText = 'start Comm';
            $interval.cancel(stop);
            stop=undefined;
        }
    };

});
```

I believe that the problem is within this function:

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $scope.machineID = machineIDs[i];
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMachine?machine=' + $scope.machineID).success(function(data) {
                $scope.data[ $scope.machineID ] = data;
            });
    };
};
```

When I run this script, I see only that the *last* machine ID changes. An example output on the browser when the script is running is the following:

```
{"machineID_1":"0","machineID_2":"0","machineID_3":"2.37252542925"}
```

The value for `"machineID_3"` keeps changing every 2 seconds like it should, while that for `"machineID_1"` amd `"machineID_2"` remains 0.

I can see from my Python output that the server is getting the correct get requests every 2 seconds, as in the example shown below.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:32] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_3 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:34] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:34] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_2 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:34] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_3 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:36] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 13
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:36] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_2 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 16:33:36] "GET /dataMachine?machine=machineID_3 HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

Am I missing something in the scoping rules?

**Resources:**

Entire contents of the Bottle Server:

```
import bottle
from bottle import response
from numpy.random import normal

import json
import pandas as pd 

app = bottle.Bottle()

# the decorator
def enable_cors(fn):
    def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
        # set CORS headers
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

        if bottle.request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            # actual request; reply with the actual response
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return _enable_cors

@app.route('/dataMachine')
@enable_cors
def simulatedMachineData():

    prevVals = {'machineID_1': 0,'machineID_2': 0,'machineID_3': 0,}
    devVals = {'machineID_1': 5.3,'machineID_2': 2.1,'machineID_3': 7.1,}    

    dictVals  = bottle.request.query.decode()
    machineID = dictVals.get('machine', '')
    if machineID not in devVals.keys(): return '-1'
    prevVals[machineID] += normal(scale=devVals[machineID])
    return str(prevVals[machineID])
```

Entire contents of the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Plotly Graph Plotter Directive for AngularJS - Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app3.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testBidirection">

Testing the return Values ...
<div  ng-controller="tempCntrl">

    <button ng-click='toggleComm()'>{{buttonText}}</button>
    <hr>
    {{data}}
    <hr>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the for loop.. should machineIDs[i]; be $scope.machineIDs[i];?

Comment: I tried all variations of adding `$scope` everywhere, including `$scope.i`, Using a different form of the `for` loop (e.g. `for (machineID in $scope.data)`) etc. Nothing seems to work :(

Comment: trying adding $scope.apply() in  $http.get success method

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Just starting with AngularJS. What is `$scope.apply()`?

Comment: I see that you have already got the solution to this problem. Nonethe less go through this link to know about $scope.$apply() http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see couple of problems in your code in the following lines.

> $scope.machineID = 'machineID_1';

Why you assigned this in to $scope variable? As I can see you only use it send machine id to the server inside your loop. If you don't use this variable inside your view, this should be corrected as follows.

```
var machineID = 'machineID_1';
```

> `$scope.getData = function(){
>           for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>                   $scope.machineID = machineIDs[i];
>                   $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMachine?machine=' + $scope.machineID).success(function(data) {
>                       $scope.data[ $scope.machineID ] = data;
>                   });
>           };
>       };`

Send Http call to a server is asynchronous. So if you do it like above, Your code may send 3 http requests to server with machineId=3. Because, of asynchronous manner, your loop will finish the execution before all http calls send. It should be corrected as follows. And also, you assigned response of the server call as follows.

> $scope.data[ $scope.machineID ] = data;

Now the $scope.machineID may be equal to 3 because of the asynchronous behavior of the http calls. So even you get data fro all 3 machine IDS, actually you assigned the values for machineId 3.

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMachine?machine=' + machineIDs[i]).success(function(data) {
                $scope.data[machineIDs[i]] = data;
            });
    };
};
```

**UPDATE**

```
    $scope.getData = function(){
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var machineId=machineIDs[i];
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dataMachine?machine=' + machineId).success((function(machineId) {
                 return function(data) {
                 $scope.data[machineId] = data;
               }
        })(machineId));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. Did not work. The reason I used `$scope.machineID` is because I thought that `machineID` couldnt be accessed from within the `$http.get` request ...

Comment: If you see from the server logs, the three calls always happen. However, if I try your suggestion (which I had already tried), I `machineIDs[i]` inside the scope becomes undefined. Here is what I see on the browser ... `{"machineID_1":"0","machineID_2":"0","machineID_3":"0","undefined":"0.0299554435569"} `

Comment: Does your server return back the machineId or only the value?

Comment: Only a value. This is a contrived example. Basically each machine will eventually return only the current measurement value in production.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to send machineId with the value from the server. Something like below. {"machineId":"1","value":"2"}. Because your server knows the machine Id.

Comment: @ssm You can do it without change anything from the server side. Check my updated answer. Check following stack overflow answer for more details.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116815/how-to-pass-a-value-to-an-angularjs-http-success-callback

Comment: Excellent, excellent. Now with the current modification, the program is working fine!!

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer posted by Madura Pradeep, to see the source of the problem consider the following:

$http calls are asynchronous and the success function is called only when the response is received from the server. Also HTTP requests are significantly slower than a simple for loop execution. Therefore by the time the first response is received and the success function called the loop has terminated and the loop variable `i == undefined` and `$scope.machineID == 'machineID_3'`. As a result, all three return values get assigned to `$scope.data[ 'machineID_3' ]`

Comment: Thanks Niko! I understand the problem, and more importantly, the solution now.